# Save data to firestore from google cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, iot

I am new to IOT and firestore.

I am trying to save data to firestore using cloud function (MQTT).

Following is the code:

```
exports.helloPubSub = (event, callback) => {

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firestore);

const db = admin.firestore()
//admin.initializeApp();
console.log("Start");

  var docRef = db.collection('users').doc('alovelace');

var setAda = docRef.set({
  first: 'Ada',
  last: 'Lovelace',
  born: 1815
});
};
```

I am getting following errors in view logs :

"Function execution took 22 ms, finished with status: 'error'"

Any suggestion

Also after some changes I am getting error - Error: Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function

My package.json is

```
{
"name": "functions",
"description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
"dependencies": {
"@google-cloud/vision": "^0.12.0",
"async": "^2.5.0",
"consolidate": "^0.14.5",
"express": "^4.15.4",
"firebase-admin": "^5.4.0",
"firebase-functions": "^0.7.0",  
"firebase-tools": "3.15.4",  
"handlebars": "^4.0.10",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"js-levenshtein": "^1.1.3",
"json-query": "^2.2.2"
},
"private": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting following error message

> Error: Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the
>   latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function

You need to update firebase CLI to deploy cloud function

> npm i --save firebase-functions@latest

There was a breaking change introduced in firebase-tools@3.17.x which requires your project to upgrade firebase-functions to the latest version.

However, firebase-functions@latest also requires firebase-admin@latest (at the time of writing this answer firebase-admin@5.11.0. Once all packages are upgraded, this problem should be solved.

Another alternative is to downgrade your global firebase-tools to 3.16.0, which lets you use older firebase-functions and firebase-admin packages.